I want to use Alias in Spring Boot
I'm currently working on a shopping mall project, and I've been in charge of the product.
So I've created ProductDto from Spring, created mapper.xml, created the ProductDao interface, and also created ProductDaoImpl that implemented it.
Now I'm trying to run a test code for ProductDaoImpl, but when I keep getting errors.
mybatis-config.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <typeAliases>
        <typeAlias alias="ProductDto" type="com.toy2.shop29.product.domain.ProductDto"/>
    </typeAliases>
</configuration>


productMapper.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="com.toy2.shop29.dao.ProductMapper">

    <select id="select" parameterType="int" resultType="ProductDto">
        SELECT product_id,
               product_name,
               small_category_id,
               brand_id,
               price,
               sale_ratio,
               is_exclusive,
               created_date,
               created_id,
               updated_date,
               updated_id
        FROM product
        where product_id = #{product_id}
    </select>
...

ProductDaoImpl.java
package com.toy2.shop29.product.dao;

import com.toy2.shop29.product.domain.ProductDto;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDao {

    @Autowired
    SqlSession session;

    String namespace = "com.toy2.shop29.dao.ProductMapper.";

    //read
    @Override
    public ProductDto select(int product_id){
        return session.selectOne(namespace + "select",product_id); 
    }
...

ProductDaoImplTest.java
package com.toy2.shop29.product.dao;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@SpringBootTest
class ProductDaoImplTest {

    @Autowired
    ProductDao productDao;

    @Test
    void select() {
        assertTrue(productDao!=null);

    }
...

---
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'session': Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionTemplate' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception with message: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'file [C:\Users\user\Desktop\new-folder\KDT_DBE1_Toy_Project2\shop29\build\resources\main\mapper\ProductMapper.xml]'

I think the problem is that ProductMapper.xml wrote resultType="ProductDto" with full name instead of ProductDto.
I changed it to fullname, resultType="com.to.shop2.product.domain.productDto" instead of ProductDto, and it doesn't show testcode failure.
I think it's a problem caused by a bad mapping somewhere

Is there any reason you use XML-based configuration?

I was studying with Spring Legacy, but I used Spring Boot for the first time, so I don't know well yet. When I searched it, it said it doesn't matter if I use config.xml, so I tried it

Stop using the outdated xml based configuration.

Converting outside of xml based configuration is definitely encouraged but as the documentation states here "If you absolutely must use XML based configuration, we recommend that you still start with a @Configuration class. You can then use an @ImportResource annotation to load XML configuration files."
